# Why upvotes no more reflected in the drop down after reaching the rep cap?

Tags: support, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit, achievements-dialog

Earlier, when I got an upvote after reaching the rep cap, the rep indicator was highlighted (become green, as if you got an important  badge) and when I click it, I will see highlighted post (if you already received up votes on this post that day), which I got an upvote on.

Now, when I get upvote after reaching the rep cap, nothing else indicates it except the rep tab in my profile.

Comment: There is no achievement to highlight. There is no change in reputation, nor did you earn a badge.

Comment: There was a bug recently, where new reputation was indicated similarly to getting a new badge. That's fixed now. It might have been what you noticed.

Comment: @Martijn At least, it increases my tag score :)

Comment: @Frank No, it is not that bug. And not what I noticed.

Comment: @Frank: *everyone* noticed that one; it was an error in the CSS. This is about hitting the daily reputation cap instead.

Comment: @nicael: sure, but that is only interesting when you get a badge for it. By the time you hit the rep cap, do you really want to see another `+1` on yet another old answer? I for one don't. I can go look at my reputation tab if I want to see that much detail.

Comment: Last time I hit the cap (July 16, this year) I didn't get notifications, and I thought that was normal. I thought it only notified you of actual positive changes to your rep. Interesting.

Comment: @Frank: it *is* entirely normal. The achievement box never notifies you of upvotes, it notifies you of positive score changes. Upvotes on CW posts also don't show up, for example.

Comment: @Martijn Exactly how I thought it was, then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The achievement box shows you *positive score changes*, and badges earned.

It never showed you upvotes on posts, only the effects of those upvotes on your score and your badge count. Upvotes on community wiki posts don't earn you reputation either, and thus won't show in your achievements dropdown either.

Since there are no positive score changes for upvotes after you hit the cap, there is nothing to show in the achievements box. Accepts and bounty awards do give you positive score and so those are shown.

As someone who hits the reputation cap every day, I'd really like to keep it this way. I can always visit my profile reputation tab to see that detail.

Comment: It did. For example, when I got 20 upvotes on some answer and then get a 21st upvote, it used to highlight the indicator with green, after I clicked it, it showed "+200 [post title]" highlighted with light blue.

Comment: @nicael: it has never done that, I think you must have gotten that confused with something else. Again, I hit the cap every day, I'd have noticed by now. :-P

Comment: ^^not for me either.

Comment: Not that I hit the cap often...

Comment: Ok, maybe its my old bad memory.